# Getting the IsAuthenticated status on WCF Data Services within the client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-security

I have a wcf data service which authenticates the user with custom basic authentication. I used the tutorial on MSDN Blogs [OData and Authentication – Part 6 – Custom Basic Authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication.aspx). So after authenticating the user against a database, the service sets

```
var principal = new GenericPrincipal( new GenericIdentity("user") );
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

Within my service I can access the principals auth status via

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```

Is there also a chance to get the IsAuthenticated status on my WPF client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic authentication is performed for every request. Your client doesn't keep any state related to authentication (except pre-authentication which skips 401 handshake). If your service requires authentication you know that you are authenticated if your call to WCF-Data Service succeeds. If you are not authenticated you will receive exception.

Comment: Thank you for your short but clear answer. Can you give me some keywords what to search for permanent authentication (Tokens?) against a wcf (data service)?

Comment: That is usually called security session or security context but I don't think WCF Data Service has any support for that.